# MacBook Pro won't start since deleting various files

Tags: macos

I removed some ".dylib" files because BitDefender Virus Scan told me so. I wanted to remove all of Genieo's stuff but I presumably missed the "launch.conf" file. Had no access to it.

Now my Mac freezes while starting up. The big problem is that the DVD-drive is out of work since a long time ago, so I can't reboot with the installer disc. Also safe mode doesn't work.

I think I have OS X 10.6.9 on a MacBook Pro

Comment: has the BitDefender ever found a actual Virus?

Comment: yeah i found 4 files and said it couldn't move them to quaranatine. it gave the option to search for them manually and i just deleted them... stupid me...

Comment: it found 4 files related to genioe... sorry typo

Comment: it's adware or spyware, not a virus i think

Comment: yeah..stupid...if it can't move them to quarantine they are probably protected system files. Lesson learned the hard way :(

Comment: try using the build in Restore by holding cmd-r during start up.

Comment: cmd r makes nothing - still gray, apple logo and spinning wheel

Comment: give it time, it needs to repair stuff...

Comment: What kind of MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 1):

Use single user mode to remove launchd.conf

Comment: Please could you expand this answer to provide more detailed steps. Maybe how to get into single user mode and from the command line delete the appropriate file.

Answer (score 0):

That's what will happen if you delete some `dylib` files.

As long as I remembered long time ago, (for Mac OS X 10.6.x) if you have a spare mac or pc, you can network boot  your macbook pro.

I think all you need to do is, connect both machine to same network (using wired), insert the install DVD into the another machine, install something like "Network boot", run it. Then on your macbook pro, when booting, hold `option` key, the network boot option should show up in your boot options.

Answer (score 0):

ok thanks everyone. i had to bring my mac to professional help. they newly installed the system and put the data back from a disc image they created first.